# How To Import Lodash for Smallest Build Sizes

Tags: javascript, lodash

I care about my javascript app build sizes.  I do what I can (within reason) to keep build sizes as small as possible.

Currently, my imports look like this:

```
import * as _ from 'lodash';
```

I've heard that "granular" imports (like below) can improve build size, but I'm not seeing the results I would expect:

```
import {get, map, set} from 'lodash';
```

What is the best way to import lodash to achieve small total build size?

Comment: We switched to [lodash-es](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash-es) for this reason also but you can just tree shake via specifity like `import foo from 'lodash/foo'` since  `from 'lodash'` still brings in the whole thing.

Comment: I had considered / learned about `lodash/foo` method, but felt like a lot of extra work, esp. for a refactor... but lodash-es seems like it might be promising...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Build sizes are VERY important for getting users engaged and retained - great question.  I have had a similar issue, and these days want to create as small of builds as possible.

I constructed a quick test using [source-map-explorer](https://github.com/danvk/source-map-explorer) - a simple tool to analyze after you run a build on your project (e.g. Angular, React).  While this tool can be very useful for analyzing what is in your bundles, keep in mind it is minified (as your build process would do) but not gzipped.  Thus it is not what your users would experience, assuming you are on a good host using mod_deflate or a server with similar gzip/Brotli/etc compression.

Here's what I did to test using a popular library: React.  I followed instructions using create-react-app then created several variants and build them using `yarn run build`.

- Test 0: create-react-app (non-typescript)
- Test 1: added lodash via `import * as _ from 'lodash'`
- Test 2: removed lodash, added lodash-es and did `import { upperCase } from 'lodash-es'`
- Test 3: removed lodash-es, added back in lodash and did `import { upperCase } from 'lodash'`

After the build process, I did a command line gzip to get the approximate "web user" gzip size. `gzip *.js` from the build output directory.

My results? Well, the runtime-main does not vary at all. The main varies slightly with different text, such as calling the included function to ensure upperCase is actually "baked in" to the build and not just discarded. I'm not concerned about those sizes so will ignore that.

Thus I'll summarize using the chunk.js.gz size (full results below):

- Test 0: 41177 bytes (baseline)
- Test 1: 65540 bytes (+24363 bytes to use one function, ouch!)
- Test 2: 43203 bytes (+2026 bytes to use one function - *much better*!)
- Test 3: 65540 bytes (+24363 bytes again, still hurts)

The conclusion?  Use lodash-es for granular importing.  Also, for code clarity, and not overriding other function names such as map, I have settled on this strategy:

`import { map as _map, get as _get } from 'lodash-es'`.

```
Directory and file sizes thanks to `tree --du`

├── [ 42787] cra-default-test-0
│ ├── [ 41177] 2.284b2af8.chunk.js.gz
│ ├── [ 642] main.a1384886.chunk.js.gz
│ └── [ 808] runtime-main.3ba3833f.js.gz
├── [ 67174] cra-all-lodash-test-1
│ ├── [ 65540] 2.ef604131.chunk.js.gz
│ ├── [ 666] main.c259429e.chunk.js.gz
│ └── [ 808] runtime-main.3ba3833f.js.gz
├── [ 44845] cra-lodash-es-uppercase-only-test-2
│ ├── [ 43203] 2.2852311b.chunk.js.gz
│ ├── [ 674] main.131e67d8.chunk.js.gz
│ └── [ 808] runtime-main.3ba3833f.js.gz
├── [ 67188] cra-lodash-uppercase-only-test-3
│ ├── [ 65540] 2.0ccbb0bd.chunk.js.gz
│ ├── [ 680] main.c3d7426c.chunk.js.gz
│ └── [ 808] runtime-main.3ba3833f.js.gz
```

Comment: It's lodash as es modules. Good stuff for typescript lovers. PS [webpack bundle analyzer](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/webpack-bundle-analyzer) is pretty darn handy also.

Comment: Answering in Spanish, "¡No!" ;)  It is "The Lodash library exported as ES modules.", see https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash-es.  There is also a "lodash core build" (https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/Build-Differences) that is small if your project can deal with the limitations.

Comment: @ChrisW.  ES modules shouldn't require TypeScript, in fact this sample React project did not have TS support, such as starting it with `npx create-react-app my-app --typescript`.

Comment: @ryanm Never said they required anything, just more modern syntax for folks getting used to the new conventions, poorly worded I suppose.